# Routing to KMS on another network/domain

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, activation, kms

This question is about KMS activation over a different network from the one my workstation is connected to. 
The software I am dealing with is Windows 7 Enterprise and MS Office 2013

**Scenario**

I manage a LAN for my company. We have our own internal AD and DNS/DHCP servers. 
However, Our physical workstations are owned and managed by a Corporation and they handle licensing of the workstation software and manage the KMS servers.

I can physically plug the workstations into the CORP LAN and Domain and force activation, but this is basically the worst case scenario.

**My Goal:**

My Goal is to create a constant static route to kms.corp.com through a router that is connected to both networks. I want the workstations to then have DNS records that automatically point to the proper host for KMS activation.

I drew a diagram of the scenario I would like to have:
[image: KMS Goal]

Now creating the routes is easy, what I don't understand is the DNS settings I need to create in order to allow the machines to properly access the KMS activation server.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you could probably use the `Manually Create SRV Records in DNS` method in this article in conjunction with Conditional Forwarders to achieve this.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff793405.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Glad to help...